# Using firefox extension storage

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm able to run this extension somehow:

https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/beastify

On clicking the Browser Icon `popup/choose_beast.js` is invoked.

Can somebody tell me why this code(placed in the top of `popup/choose_beast.js`) is generating exception:

```
try{
var ss = require("sdk/simple-storage");
ss.storage.myArray = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13];
}catch(e){
    alert('exception');
    console.log(e);
}
```

Here is the relevant entry in the `manifest.json`:

```
 "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/beasts-32.png",
    "default_title": "Beastify",
    "default_popup": "popup/choose_beast.html"
}
```

What is the way I can store the data in this popup html so that I can retrieve anytime in the content script?

Also under which context is this page choose_beast.html running? Background, page script or content script?

Comment: webextensions != addon sdk.

Comment: @the8472 can you please clarify?

Comment: Firefox is slowly moving towards WebExtension, which is similar to how you develop extension for chrome browser, for WebExtension you can refer to this link.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions  more info : https://clipmystuff.com/g/54-firefox-add-ons-webextension

Answer (score 5):

A web-extension should be using [`storage API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage) for this purpose.

[Here](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/master/favourite-colour/options.js) is an example usage.

Comment: Then where should I use sdk/simple-storage ?

Comment: You won't use `simple-storage` in web extensions. Infact, you won't use any sdk module in web-extensions.

Web extensions have new api that provides somewhat identical functionality to that of addon-sdk. Since `simple-storage` api is meant to allow extensions to save their data in key-value format, the same functionality is provided by `storage API` but you may find the syntax different

Comment: Check the [linked extension](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/master/favourite-colour/) source code how it saves and retrieves data using `storage API`